# Bootstrap4 validation not working in IE 11 when adding event listener to each required field in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, webforms

I'm validating asp.net webform controls using bootstrap4 like this:

```
<form runat="server" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

 <div class="form-group">
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Amount" CssClass="form-control" Text="" required></asp:TextBox>
 </div>

 <asp:Button ID="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Then adding an event listener in javascript in a master page like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

    for (let form of forms) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {

           if (!form.checkValidity()) {
               evt.preventDefault();
               evt.stopPropagation();

           } else {

                 console.info('All form fields are now valid...');
           }

           form.classList.add('was-validated');

         });
       }
    });
```

It's working fine in Chrome & FireFox but nothing is validated in IE 11. The page just refreshes after pressing the submit button in IE11.  In the console of IE11 it says there's a syntax error on this line:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong and how I could fix this so the validation would work in IE 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my code worked fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 11 and Edge. I got it to work in those browsers too by not using the ES6 JavaScript features

1.) Had to avoid using the arrow functions:

Replaced

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
```

With

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
```

And

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
```

With

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
```

2.) the let form of forms iterator wasn't recongized either in IE 11 but since I'm only using one form I just did this instead:

```
var formName = document.getElementById('Form1');
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.